# App Certification Kit - Outlook VSTO Desktop application

Tags: vsto, windows-store, app-certification-kit, wack

I want to publish Outlook VSTO desktop app to Windows Store.
When I test it with App Certification Kit 10 it fails and no XML report is created:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit>appcert test -apptype desktop -setuppath "C:\Projects\Main\AppSetup_x64\bi
n\Debug\AppSetup_x64.msi"  -appusage peruser -reportoutputpath "C:\Projects\Main\report.xml"
    Note: Test application type - Desktop.
    Beginning execution of task Modify fault tolerant heap.
    Beginning execution of task Modify status of the TAEF service.
    Task Modify fault tolerant heap execution result was failure.
    Task Modify status of the TAEF service execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Registry key inventory.
    Task Registry key inventory execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Program inventory.
    Task Program inventory execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Attack surface analyzer.
    Beginning execution of task Digital signing.
    Task Digital signing execution result was success.
    Task Attack surface analyzer execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Do not load services and drivers in safe mode.
    Beginning execution of task Proper OS version checking.
    Task Do not load services and drivers in safe mode execution result was success.
    Task Proper OS version checking execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Multi user enable.
    Task Multi user enable execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Do not force an immediate reboot during installation.
    Task Do not force an immediate reboot during installation execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Modify Program Compatibility Assistant service.
    Task Modify Program Compatibility Assistant service execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task User mode hooking using AppInit_DLLs.
    Beginning execution of task Crashes and hangs.
    Task User mode hooking using AppInit_DLLs execution result was success.
    Task Crashes and hangs execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Process install trace files.
    Beginning execution of task Modify local Windows Error Reporting settings.
    Task Modify local Windows Error Reporting settings execution result was success.
    Task Process install trace files execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Program inventory.
    Task Program inventory execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Process install trace files.
    Task Process install trace files execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Installed programs.
    Task Installed programs execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Dependency information.
    Beginning execution of task Proper OS version checking.
    Task Proper OS version checking execution result was success.
    Task Dependency information execution result was failure.
    Beginning execution of task Process install trace files.
The application failed to install under a higher version of Windows. Windows App Certification Kit will now retry installing the application
 under different settings.
    Task Process install trace files execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Program inventory.
    Task Program inventory execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Process install trace files.
    Task Process install trace files execution result was success.
    Beginning execution of task Installed programs.
    Task Installed programs execution result was failure.

Testing cannot continue unless an application is successfully installed, including a discoverable shortcut and an entry in add/remove programs.
```

During the test the App Cert Kit asks from me to install the MSI and after that, I assume it tries to run the installed application.
The problem is that the installed app is actually a set of DLLs that is copied to the MS Office folder.
It is not executable, it has no Desktop icon, but it still has an entry in the Add/Remove Programs.

App certification Kit 10.0 runs under Windows 2012 Server, DLLs compiled with Visual Studio 2012.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: This is not what the toolkit is for.  It is for testing windows store projects you and sending to the windows store.

Comment: That's what I need it for. To test my windows store project.